# creating a bridge for a KVM

Tags: networking, virtualization

Trying to create a Bridge setup for my KVM there are some things I don´t very well understand, I that I cannot clarify reading other articles on the same subject

```
Configure Bridged Network Interface
Before we proceed you will need to have the following information to setup the new bridge interface.
    Bridge Name: This will be the name of the new bridge interface. We will use br0.
    Interface Name: The name of the network interface which will serve as the bridge slave. This should one of the interface from the output of the above command.
    IP Address: IP address for the bridge interface.
    Subnet Mask: The subnet mask for the network interface you have chosen.
    Gateway IP: The IP of the gateway for the network.
    DNS Addresses: The IPs of the DNS servers you wish to use.
```

In order to understand this correctly some lines of my ifconfig

```
ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.26  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
```

The interface name : that is current the name of the physical wired connection the "enp3s0"  above
The IP address : an address for the VM in my network IP range eg. 192.168.1.61
The Netmask is the netmask of my network 255.255.255.0
The gateway is the gateway of my current network 192.168.1.1
the DNS adrr : are the same as on my network

Is that the correct understanding of the article